# What is the rationale for a government trying to block one of its citizens for becoming EU prosecutor?

Tags: european-union, government, romania

Romania’s former head of the anti-corruption directorate DNA has [significant chances of becoming European Prosecutor's Office](https://www.romania-insider.com/kovesi-runs-european-prosecutor-office/).

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Public_Prosecutor), an EU Prosecutor can investigate fraud across EU, but there are some limitations:

> The EPPO may request a suspect's arrest, but **this must be confirmed by
>   the relevant national authority**.

[This article](https://twincitiesbusinessradio.com/news/world/eu-voices-concern-as-romania-moves-to-block-prosecutor?apt_credirect=1) argues about Romanian government moving to block Kovesi to become EU prosecutor:

> Prosecutors applying for the post of European chief prosecutor must be
>   treated fairly, the European Commission said Thursday, after **Romania
>   moved to block one of its own nationals.**

The same article emphasizes government's efforts to undermine the judiciary:

> Romania's ruling Social Democracy Party embarked on a contentious
>   judicial overhaul two years ago, sparking protests. Critics, including
>   the EU and the U.S., claimed **the changes would undermine the
>   independence of the judiciary and efforts to combat high-level
>   corruption.**

Since one cannot be arrested unless a national prosecutor asks for it, I am wondering why make such a tremendous effort to stop a person becoming an EU prosecutor.

**Question:** What is the rationale for a government trying to block one of its citizens for becoming EU prosecutor?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*Retribution*

The rationale of the Romanian government in this case is that the [individual in question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laura_Codru%C8%9Ba_K%C3%B6vesi), in her role as head of the Romanian Anti-Corruption agency, has launched investigations on more or less the whole political establishment of Romania.

Becoming a major EU prosector would, most probably, give her more investigative power. And that's something you do not want, if you're on the receiving end of the anti-corruption investigations.

See relevant articles in the media, e.g. [1](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-38894296), [2](https://www.bbc.com/news/blogs-eu-31537338)